# Use environment variable in Typescript with ParcelJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, environment-variables, parceljs

Migrating a react app built with ParcelJS to Typescript/React, I encounter some environment variables issues. Actually, the issue seems to only impact the error output since the environment variables (URL, used in a `<a>` tag) works properly on the webpage.

Here is the terminal output:

```
/Users/---/Projects/---/---/src/cart/index.tsx(xxx,xxx)
Cannot find name 'process'.
126 |       method: "post",
127 |       url: `${process.env.URL}/checkout`,
    |               ^^^^^^^
128 |       data: cart,
```

I tried several approaches, as `import * as process from "process"` which didn't fix the issue:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'process'.
'./node_modules/process/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/process` if it exists or add a new 
declaration (.d.ts)     file containing `declare module 'process';`
  > 6 | import * as process from "process";
  |                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Nevertheless if I try to output the variable that works :

```
const ENV = process.env.MIDDLEWARE_URL;
console.log('ENV', ENV);
```

Browser output:

```
ENV http://localhost:3000
```

Finally, I can't figure out if this is a Parcel issue or a TSConfig issue.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In Node.js TypeScript development, `@types/node` package is supposed to be used for Node-specific declarations including `process`. It isn't suitable for browser because it likely has nothing in common with Node.js environment except `process` global.

`process` built-in module import is redundant in Node.js and certainly shouldn't be used in browser, because there's no such module (even though there is [shim module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/process), it isn't needed for `process.env`).

If `process` was defined by a bundler (ParcelJS) in client-side script, type declaration should be provided for it in custom type file (e.g. typings/custom.d.ts):

```
declare const process: {
    env: {
        ENV: string;
        URL: string;
    }
}
```

Custom typings path should be specified in TypeScript configuration as well:

```
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"]
```

Comment: "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"] (and was sufficient, no need to redeclare process in my case) perfectly solved the issue. Thanks for explanation though.

Comment: Actually I wonder if  "typeRoots": ["./typings"] with a process.d.ts could be a better solution, as I try to limit side effects during the migrating to TS. I'll try this instead, that seems way more "under control" :)

Comment: This is how it's usually done. You will need node_modules/@types there any way.

Comment: I'm now confused. When I add node_modules/@types/react-dom to custom typeRoots, I have an error in process.d.ts "cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'process'". I feel like ParcelJS "parcel-plugin-typescript" do things undercover but I can't figure out what. Actually my stablest implementation is `"typeRoots": ["./typings"]` with a process.d.ts `declare const process: {
    env: any
}`

Comment: @Kleioz I see. You will likely need types from node_modules/@types any way, so they shouldn't be excluded. Yes, that's the problem with @types/react-dom, it has a dependency on @types/node, while it isn't supposed to. See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/21310 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18588 . I guess, `declare const process` should be commented in custom.d.ts for now, until the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

To add to a comment answer left by @Kleioz because I still had to google what was happening...

The solution was to add `typeRoots` to the TypeScript config. This essentially tells the compiler where the node_module declarations are. You can also pass through a folder for custom declarations if required.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"]
    ...
  }
}
```

`./typings` is your folder for custom declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the correct type definitions as a dev dependency solves the problem: `npm install @types/parcel-bundler --save-dev`